# How do I protect a VPC from deletion?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

We have a VPC with 50 EC2 servers in it. There is a VPN connection to the rest of our corporate network.

How do we make sure the VPC doesn't get deleted by mistake by some script and we lose it?

There seems to be no feature of termination protection for VPC's.

Comment: Only tangentially related, but you should keep backups and snapshots, and keep those in cold (offline) long-term storage. So, archival WORM drives. High-density tape drives are industry standard for backups. Worth knowing on the offchance you aren't actually able to change deletion credentials or revoke privileges.

Answer (score 3):

Do not deploy any credentials that have the capability of deleting VPCs. Credentials should be given only the specific rights they need and no more. Additionally, your root credentials should never be used except in an emergency. Lock them up in a safe and use IAM users for day-to-day operations.

Comment: I was going to point out that it's virtually impossible to accidentally delete a VPC -- you have to first deletes all the instances, route tables, gateways... just about anything allocated against a VPC will prevent its deletion, so there's no need for termination protection.  And, even though that's all true, this answer is even better.